# Selecionar todos elementos de uma classe CSS exceto o $(this) com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Seja o HTML abaixo como exemplo:

```
<div>
    <a class="link">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link">Link 3</a>
<div>
```

Como posso selecionar todos elementos de uma classe exceto o elemento `$(this)` que eu cliquei?

Estou tentando usar o seletor [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) do CSS junto com o jQuery sem sucesso:

```
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    $(".link" + ":not(" + $(this) + ")").hide(); // Isto não funciona
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisaria nem algo como o :not, bastaria fazer o hide e depois o show apenas para o selecionado, assim:

```js
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    $(".link").hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <a class="link">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link">Link 3</a>
<div>
```

Agora se for usar com jQuery-ui e animações dele o efeito vai fazer sumir e mostrar o this, o que pode parecer até um bug, neste caso especifico poderia apenas usar o .filter assim:

```js
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    var $this = this;

    $(".link").filter(function (index, element) {
         return element !== $this;
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <a class="link">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link">Link 3</a>
<div>
```

Ou mais fácil ainda, usando o .not, assim:

```js
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    $(".link").not(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <a class="link">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link">Link 3</a>
<div>
```

O filter seria mais interessante para um filtragem mais complexa, para o seu caso o .not já resolve.

---

API do jQuery:

- https://api.jquery.com/not/#not-function
- https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function

Comment: WOW! Três formas! Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento.